# single quotes to strings in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just want to know that is there any shortcut to automatically add quotes to each string in IN CLAUSE?

For ex: I got more than 10 tables to check `IN CLAUSE`

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME in (dimproduct,dimproductCateogory,dimproductSubCateogory,FactInternetSales)
and COLUMN_NAME like '%eng%'
```

in the above example I want output like this: adding single quote to each string

```
where TABLE_NAME in ('dimproduct','dimproductCateogory','dimproductSubCateogory','FactInternetSales')
```

any help?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Why don't you just put the 10 tables in the `IN` clause with quotes?  If you have to list the tables individually anyway, whats a couple extra characters?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I know that I have to add single quotes to each table but, I just want to know any shortcut way to add quotes to each string in IN CLAUSE. Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify what you are doing, and why you need a different way to put apostrophes in the query than typing. Just typing 20 apostrophes would be a lot faster than asking a question about it, so there is obviously something that isn't conveyed in the question.

Comment: @Guffa, thanks for reply. I am happy to type 20 quotes but, I just want to improve my knowledge. Is there any other way to add quotes by using any in built functions. Thanks

Comment: @KK1960: I don't know of any function specifically for that. Depending on what you use to edit it, you might be able to select the values and replace `,` with `','` in the selection, then it's just the first and last apostrophes to type.

Comment: Do a search & replace for , -> ',' and then add one to the start and end?

Comment: Thanks all for the above suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to use the replace dialogue in SSMS.

Paste the query into SSMS and select the entire "in" list including the open and close brackets.

Select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the "Quick Replace".

Enter `{[^,()]+}` into the "find what" and `'\1'` into the Replace, ensure "Selection" is selected for the scope and select "Use Regular Expressions" in the final option.

Then click "Replace All"

[image]

Comment: If possible.. Can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: @GK1960 the `{}` delimits a tagged expression. The `[^,()]` means match any character that is not (`^`) in the set comma, open bracket, close bracket. The `+` means one or more times. This tagged result is numbered `1`. The replace surrounds it with quotes and adds it back in place of the match.

Comment: Thanks @ Martin Smith, for explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME in (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                     WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'dimproduct%'
                        OR  TABLE_NAME = 'FactInternetSales')
and COLUMN_NAME like '%eng%'
```

OR

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t  ON C.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE (t.name  LIKE 'dimproduct%'
        OR 
       t.name = 'FactInternetSales')
 AND c.name LIKE '%eng%'
```